# How to add 1 hour, 1/2 hour , 20 mins in excel

Tags: excel

[image]

How to add custom values like time which is entered in hour and mins in excel.
Please refer the image.
For example,
1 hour
20 mins
30 mins

Total-1 hour 50 mins

Comment: Do math. Convert hours to minutes, add all minutes, convert back to hours and minutes.

Comment: where should i write that function?

Comment: where do you want the result to appear?

Comment: like shown in the image i want to show month wise summation

Comment: You could use a long Excel formula to parse, split, and convert strings to number. If you're using Excel 365, you might simplify the expressions with lambdas. If you don't mind writing VBA code, you could create a user-defined function and use that UDF in a cell formula

Comment: Maybe you could get the user to enter the data as a time, rather than as a text string.  If you must enter it as a text string, you should be using data validation to prevent spelling mistakes and other data entry errors.